# Identify Line Terminators Of Text File Using R

Tags: r, carriage-return, linefeed

I have been using R to prepare files for an ETL process, and until recently, all of the text files I've been working with have had CRLF (Carriage Return & Line Feed) line terminators. Now, the line terminators on the new text files are being delivered in a mixed/inconsistent format- sometimes CRLF & sometimes LF only. Is there a function in R that will allow me to scan the text file prior to import, and tell me what the line terminator of the first line is? I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What error do you face?

Comment: Not an error in R. We use R to unzip the files & rename them. We have an SSIS package that we developed in VS for our ETL process, but the inconsistent line terminators wreak havoc- so we're trying to anticipate which files we'll have issues with before they get to that stage.

Comment: It would be much easier if you can simulate the issue